# Equation include floor function,where is the mistake?

Tags: calculus

I was solving this problem $$\lfloor x\rfloor+3x=1\to x=n+\left\{x\right\}\\n+3(n+\left\{x\right\})=1\\4n+3\left\{x\right\}=1 \to n=\frac14$$ I got no answer ,but the book says $x=\frac13$

when I put it down into eq. works fine . where is my mistake ? Is there other method for solve this eq.?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchang . You have two cases there ,but you do not solve second condition .

Comment: What is the secon condition ?

Comment: $$4n \in \{0,\pm4,\pm8 ,\pm 12,... \}$$ this is what you must note

Comment: Aside on writing: $\to$ does not mean "and the next step is". $P \to Q$ as you've used it generally means "Since $P$ is true, we conclude $Q$ is true too", which has nothing to do with what you are *actually* doing (which is introducing an aside where you've defined $n$ through a relationship with $x$).

Comment: Another aside on writing: there usually are words between equations in mathematical writing. You will see these in any good math textbook. In a classroom lecture your instructor may write one equation after another, but they almost surely _say_ some words that are not just reading the equations while they are doing that. Words like that should be in your writing too, to explain why you thought you should write the next equation, and why we should believe it is true. It is better not to try to use symbols as abbreviations for those words.

Answer (score 2):

Except for neglecting to specify (when you first use the symbol $n$)
that $n$ is an integer,
your method was fine up until the very last step.
Indeed, given the initial problem statement, it is true that
$$ 4n + 3\{x\} = 1.$$

Now this is possible to solve by a combination of reasoning and trial-and-error: try $n = 1,$ and you may observe that $n \geq 1$ is too high;
try $n = -1,$ and you observe that $n \leq -1$ is too low;
but $n = 0$ works.

---

Another possible approach is to divide both sides of the equation by $4.$
We then have
$$ n + \frac34\{x\} = \frac14.$$

Now for the two sides to be equal, their integer parts must be equal, and their fractional parts also must be equal.
Let's look at the fractional parts.
On the right side, of course, the fractional part is $\frac14.$
On the left side, since $n$ is an integer, its fractional part is zero.
The fractional part of the entire left side of the equation therefore is just the fractional part of $\frac34\{x\}.$

But since $0 \leq \{x\} < 1,$ it follows that $0 \leq \frac34\{x\} < \frac34,$ so the integer part of $\frac34\{x\}$ is $0$ and the fractional part is $\frac34\{x\}$ itself. Therefore
$$ \frac34\{x\} = \frac14.$$

Solve for $\{x\}$:
$$ \{x\} = \frac13.$$

Now put that value of $\{x\}$ into any of the previous equations involving $n,$ and you can show that $n = 0.$ Hence
$$ x = n + \{x\} = 0 + \frac13 = \frac13.$$

---

Alternatively, after showing that $n + \frac34\{x\} = \frac14,$ you could look at the integer part on both sides of the equation.
Since $0 \leq \frac34\{x\} < \frac34$ (for the same reasons as before),
the integer part of $\frac34\{x\}$ can only be $0.$
Of course the integer part of $\frac14$ also is $0,$ so setting the integer parts of both sides of the equation equal, we have
$$ n + 0 = 0.$$
Therefore $n=0,$ and putting this in any earlier equation involving $n$ and $\{x\},$ you can show that $ \{x\} = \frac13.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $0\leq \{x\}<1$ so $3\times 0\leq 3\{x\}<3\times 1$ 
$$ \quad{\lfloor x\rfloor+3x=1\\\to x=n+\left\{x\right\}=n+p\\\color{red}{0\leq p<1\\0\leq 3p <3}\\n+3(n+p)=1\\\Rightarrow\begin{cases}4n+3p=1 \to n=\frac14 \boxtimes\\n=0\to 3p=1 \to p=\frac13\checkmark\end{cases}}$$
$$4n \in \{0,\pm4,\pm8 ,\pm 12,... \} \to 4n=0 \text{ in your equation}$$

Comment: Oh,thanks .I find my mistake now .

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve :
you may know  $\lfloor x\rfloor =k \to k\leq x<k+1$ take $1-3x=k$ so $$1-3x=k \in \mathbb{Z} ,x=\frac{1-k}{3}$$so 
$$\lfloor x\rfloor+3x=1 \\\lfloor \frac{1-k}{3}\rfloor=k\\ k < \frac{1-k}{3} \leq k+1\\$$ solve two inequality 
$$k < \frac{1-k}{3} \to 3k<1-k \to k<\frac14 \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{1-k}{3} \leq k +1\to 1-k\leq 3k+3 \to k\geq -\frac12 \tag{2}$$
$$(1) \cap (2) :\{0,1,2,,3,...\}\cap \{0,-1,-2,-3,... \}=\{0\}$$ the only possible $k=0 \to x=\frac{1-k}{3}=\frac{1-0}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Another observation:
$$\lfloor x\rfloor+3x=1\\\lfloor x\rfloor=1-3x \to 1-3x \in \mathbb{Z}$$ we know 
$$0\leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor<1$$put into inequality 
$$0\leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor<1\\0\leq x-(1-3x)<1\\1\leq 4x <2\\\frac 14\leq x<\frac 24 \to \\-\frac64 \leq -3x <-\frac 34
\\-\frac24 \leq 1-3x <\frac 14$$but $$1-3x \in \mathbb{Z} \to 1-3x=0 \\\to x=\frac13$$